# How to insert text where an empty line is, in a PDF?

Tags: windows-7, pdf

I have downloaded a pdf that I am to fill out and return.  There are lots of fields that I am to fill out after printing the PDF, but my handwriting is horrendous.

The fields are of the sort "Name: _________________________"  How can I edit the PDF to actually write my name on this line?

Comment: Please include your operating system.

Comment: Sorry, Windows 7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) is a freeware application for Windows which can add text to *.PDF files. To add text, the `Typewriter` tool is located under `Comments`.

Note: A portable version also exists and is available from [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/apps/office/foxit_reader_portable).